# Jquery calculation price of hotel and room with additional price

Tags: jquery, html, calculator

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/sando779/16wws4w1/

```html
<select name="one" id="one">
    <option value="0">Select Hotel</option>
    <option value="3000">Nirvana</option>
    <option value="6000">Laguna</option>
    <option value="9000">Palm beach</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<select name="two" id="two">
    <option>Room Type</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="tri" id="tri" value="50"/>
    <label >additional Price</label>
</p>
<div id="total"></div>
```

```js
// arrays instead of comma separated list and added base key
var data = {
    "0": ["Select Room type"],
        "3000": ["economist_0", "executive_465", "businesse_984"],
       "6000": ["economist_200", "executive_700", "businesse_800"],
        "9000": ["economist_400", "executive_800", "businesse_900"]
}

$("#one").change(function () {
    var first = $(this),
        second = $("#two"),
        third = $("#tri"),
        key = first.val(),
        // instead of the original switch code
        vals = data[key] == undefined ? data.base : data[key],
        html = [];
    // create insert html before adding
    $.each(vals, function (i, val) {
        var v = val.split('_');
        html.push('<option value="' + v[1] + '">' + v[0] + '</option>')
    });
    // no need to empty the element before adding the new content
    second.html(html.join());
});

$("#one,#two,#tri").change(function () {
    var val1 = parseInt($('#one').val()) || 0,
        val2 = parseInt($('#two').val()) || 0,
        val3 = parseInt($('#tri').val()) || 0;
    $('#total').text(val1 + val2 + val3)
})
```

I'm wanna sum the values from different types of form elements. Drop down and input. I'm stuck at the total is not automate update after I add additional price

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/16wws4w1/1/

Comment: thanks dude.. you save my live

Comment: let me post this as an answer. please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding the additional value even if the `checkbox` is not checked. you need to only add the additional value if the `checkbox` is checked. you can try this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/16wws4w1/1/